# ckeditor to respond to Dom Events

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

From  ck editor we can fire messages  `editor.fire('Test')`. and in javascript
 i was able to subscribe to event by `ckeditor.on('Test',()=>{//code here});`.
I would like to do this other way like  when dom fires an event then ck editor has to respond to that event.
How can i do it ? , any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do it above, just trigger that event in the DOM event handler.

```
ckeditor.on('specialCKEditorEvent',
    function () {
        // Whatever you want ckeditor to do
    }
);

document.addEventListener('anyDOMEvent',
    function () {
        editor.fire('specialCKEditorEvent');
    }
);
```